# Как изменить фоновую картинку и высоту в uitextfield?

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, iphone, objective-c

Пытаюсь изменить высоту и бэкграунд в UITextField.

Добавляю в viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect frameRect = fromTextField.frame;
frameRect.size.height = 100;
fromTextField.frame = frameRect;
[fromTextField.layer setCornerRadius:2.0];
fromTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"field_text_a.png"];
```

В заголовочном файле textfield обозначен как:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *fromTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fromTextField;
```

Но не работает:(
Может быть надо как-то связать с .xib файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько помню (а сейчас у меня к сожалению нет времени проверить на коде), там есть хитрость со свойством borderStyle, задник в целом и изменение высоты в частности работают не при всех вариантах этого свойства (как и на кнопках кстати, только там это style), если память мне не изменяет - нужно делать не UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, а именно это значение выставляется в ксибе по умолчанию

Comment: Проблема решена: нужно было отключить "Use autolayout"

Comment: а, про них я все время забываю - мне как-то пока везде нужна поддержка 5.х, а лейаутов там нету, приходится без них работать

Answer (score 0):

NoBorderStyle нужно установить